# How to make an ImageButton visible/invisibl

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, admob, imagebutton

I'm trying to create an imagebutton to close an ad from admob.
I've created the button in the xml with the visibility property set to "invisible" and then on java I set it to "visible" when the ad is received, but the button never become visible.
If I set it to "visible" hardcoded on the XML it appears on the screen normally.

Admob layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/layout_main">
    <ImageButton        
        android:id="@+id/close_ad"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="-36dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dip"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_close_ad" />  
</RelativeLayout>
```

Add ad:

```
private void addAd() {
    rl = (RelativeLayout) activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.admob, null);
    rl.setGravity(position);
    activity.addContentView(rl, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    AdView admobView = new AdView(activity, AdSize.BANNER, Preferences.getAdmobKey());
    admobView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
    [ ... ]
    admobView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveAd(Ad ad) {
        Log.v("JeraAdmob", "onReceiveAd");
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createCloseButton();
            }
        }, AD_SHOW_CLOSE);
    }
    });
}
```

Create button to close the ad:

```
private void createCloseButton() {
        ImageButton button = (ImageButton) rl.findViewById(R.id.close_ad);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rl.removeAllViews();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        addAd();
                        rl.bringToFront();
                    }
                }, AD_RELOAD);
            }
        });
        button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        button.bringToFront();
    }
```

Comment: are u trying to put it on top of the ad? (overlap?)

Comment: Can you rephrase your question - this sentence is ambiguous '...then on java I set it to "visible" when the ad is received, but the button never become visible. If I set it to "visible" it appears on the screen normally.'  Does that mean it does or doesn't appear when you set it to visible - you've said both!

Comment: please, show ALL parametres of the xml code of the button.

Comment: I'm trying to overlap but with a negative left margin it would appear on the left side, outside the banner.

Comment: It appears if I set the visibility "visible" hardcoded on the XML, I've tried this to check if the button was under the banner

Comment: What happens if you call createCloseButton on the main UI thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the image button after the admob layout. 

 like this:

```
<RelativeLayout ...>
    <Admob..../>
    <ImageButton..../>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 5):

button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); - is absolutely correct. Have you checked if the app really got to  this line? It seems to me that it did not.